# Printing out spaces in comments

Tags: java, html, jsf, primefaces

I am currently creating a simple comment system and I need to do a hierarchy.

Let's say comment 3 is reply to comment 2 and that is reply to comment 1. Then I want comment 1 to be left side, comment 2 slightly moved to the right of comment 1 and comment 3 slightly right of comment2 (so two times right). I have a list of comments and list of integers which is saying me which comment should be how much from the left. In the example above my list is comment1, comment2, comment3 and list of integers is 0,1,2 as the comment1 should not be moved at all, comment2 once and comment3 twice. Any idea how to translate that list value to the spacing?

I have ui:repeat for printing out comments and as I print a comment I also move the pointer to the right integer value and print it with the comment. So every comment has the right value paired to it in JSF. Only thing I need is to change that value to spacing somehow. (Possibly without another ui:repeat nested because that I suspect would be very inefficient)

Comment: And the real problem is? You can put EL in style attributes and per comment calculate a padding all basic thinking. Effectively you ask for dynamic whitespace. That is the more generic underlying question and a better title and search term for Google

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks Kukeltje for pointing me the way, it seems my judgment was clouded.

The solution (if it would be useful for somebody later):

```
<p:panel style="margin-left: #{projectBean.spaces.get(projectBean.spaceNumber)*10}%">
```

where projectBean.spaces is my list of spaces to each comment and spaceNumber is a variable I iterate over the list (bump it in my backing bean by function).